# Why am I getting warnings about missing DLLs when adding a node to a WSFC?

Tags: sql-server, windows-cluster

We're getting the following two errors when adding a node to our WSFC.

```
The node was added successfully, but the 'SQL Server Availability Group' resource type could not be installed on it.
Unable to find 'hadrres.dll' on any of the cluster nodes.

The node was added successfully, but the 'SQL Server FILESTREAM Share' resource type could not be installed on it.
Unable to find 'fssres.dll' on any of the cluster nodes.
```

This cluster is going to host an AlwaysOn Availability Group.  SQL Server 2012 is installed on both nodes, and availability groups are enabled on both.  Filestream access is also configured on both.  Another curious thing I'm seeing is that my instance on the second node doesn't appear in Configuration Manager.

[image]

Anyone know what may be going on here?

Comment: How did you install SQL? Sounds like maybe SQL wasnt installed using "New SQL Server failover cluster installation".  IE. Install Failover Clustering, and then install SQL as a cluster SQL install.

Comment: Are your SQL instances clustered?  I would expect to see those errors until that node is properly configured with clustered SQL on it.

Comment: @floyd - I'm doing an AlwaysOn AG, I thought you used standalone installation for that, since you're not going to be sharing storage?  That's what we did in our test lab when trying this and it seemed to work.  We're not combining the technologies at all either, just a simple two-node AG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled SQL Server, weirdness went away. (it may have not been a problem to begin with, though, but being safe is good when you're a little out of your realm of expertise)

Answer (score 0):

Banged my head for 3 days over this problem , solution was evict nodes/destroy the wsfc, recreated it, added nodes, created availability group, availability DB, and listener.